# location.href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari

javascript:

1. location.href("somefile.php"); // successfully working with IE
2. location.href = "somefile.php";

Ques 1. first code is not work with Safari. Why?
Ques 2. What is the difference b/w these codes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `href` is not a method, it is a property whose value is a string.
2. The first is a call on a method with a url as the argument *(incorrect)*, the second is assigning the url as the value of the property *(correct)*.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location

Answer (score 1):

i never heard of `location.href("somefile.php");`... `location.href = "somefile.php";` is the "normal" way that you should use.

Answer (score 1):

Also it's more efficient using *window.location* than *location*. So try to use :

```
window.location.href = "somefile.php";
```

(as Andy said, href is a property and in JS you specify a property value in this way: *object.property = "value"*)

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 :- It wont work because href is a property of location object, not a method.
Answer 2 :- location.href("...") denotes a method(that is invalid) while location.href is a property.